# Closed form for the sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, riemann-zeta

Is there a closed form for this sum? It's a mixing summation of different terms in the zeta function with different values of $s.$

$$ S=\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^3}+\frac{1}{3^4}+\frac{1}{4^5}+ \cdot\cdot\cdot $$

Which can be written as:

$$ \zeta_1(2)+\zeta_2(3)+\zeta_3(4)+\zeta_4(5)+\cdot\cdot\cdot $$

where the $\zeta_1(2)$ denotes the first term of $\zeta(2).$

Or as:

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{i})^{i+1} $$

I don't think there is a closed form.

Comment: I don't see a reason to relate this sum to Zeta.

Comment: Why don't you see a reason to relate this sum to Zeta?

Comment: I can't answer such a negative question. Why do you see a relation ?

Comment: I see another relation. I

Comment: I see a relation to zeta @YvesDaoust. I see how the isolated terms of different $s$ values of the zeta function are present in the sum

Comment: This doesn't mean that they are related. You could as well see terms of geometric sequences or some Taylor development.

Comment: Said differently, picking terms from different series gives an unrelated series, because a single term tells nothing about a series. You can't retrieve $\zeta(4)$ from $1/3^4$.

Comment: Just for fun though, this may be relatable to the [Sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)

Comment: @ClementC.. Yep. With $S(x)=\sum x^k/k^{k+1}$, $S'(1)=\sum 1/k^k$. The constant in the question is $S(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that Yves. I have undone the mirage of a relation I once saw before. Now I see a different summation, one with different properties.

Comment: It is unlikely that this constant has a closed-form. As pointed by @ClementC., a similar constant - $\sum i^{-i}$ - can be related to a definite integral. It is not unlikely that the principle can be extended to your sum, but this will not help. (Liouville's theorem is inconclusive on definite integrals.)